# Why is JENKINS not using environment variables in Powershell area?

Tags: powershell, jenkins-plugins

When running this inside the "Powershell" input box of a Jenkins job

```
${WORKSPACE}\MyScript.ps1 arg1 arg2
```

there is an error - **Unexpected token '\MyScript.ps1' in expression or statement**. The alternative is hardcoding the path to the script and that works great. But if I want to specify a relative path in the project structure for this, I cannot do this because of the error.

I ran into the same issue when trying to use Jenkins environment variables in the args (i.e. arg2). I used the workaround of putting it as a powershell variable $($env:BUILD_NUMBER + .... )

Comment: `& "$WORKSPACE\MyScript.ps1" arg1 arg2`

Comment: Your second statement about environment variables makes no sense.  The `$Env:` drive is **the** way to access environment variables in powershell (likewise using `%VAR%` syntax in batch)

Comment: @Incorrigible - Notice the double $. Seems that Jenkins is not simply substituting the $environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins piepleines are having some issues in extending Global Variable Expressions(param, env or simply global) in some specific circumstances. Ar you using this expression in a  clojure? Take a try one block higher and put them into normal groovy variables.